# JavaScript equivalent of this small PHP code

Tags: php, javascript, class, inheritance, static

I would like to have a 'static' method "create" that returns a new instance of a 'class' in my JavaScript code.

In PHP i would do it that way :

```
abstract class Object {
    public static function create() {
        return new static;
    }
}

class Foo extends Object { }

$foo = Foo::create();
```

In JavaScript i have :

```
var Object = function() { };

var Foo = function() { };
Foo.prototype = new Object;
```

I want to be able to do :

```
var foo = Foo.create();
```

Is it possible to do it ? If yes, what should i add ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Object is maybe already reserved, but let's say that's just for the example.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: Boolean does not inherit from Object, it inherits from Object.prototype, which is a completely different object...

Comment: yes, but object's don't inherit from Object either, they inherit from Object.prototype, which is not the same. Object has lots of static methods like keys() that don't appear on objects...

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: i agree with the point, but not the incorrect statements made in support of it. This stuff is a bit confusing, likely because there just aren't enough reserved words in JS to be as specific about pattern as other languages...

Answer (score 0):

it's actually dead simple, despite potentially confusing semantics about what is "static":

```
function Foo(){
  this.bar=true;
}

Foo.create= function(){ return new this; };

var foo = Foo.create();
```

by OP demand, alternate version to work on all constructors:

```
function Foo(){
  this.bar=true;
}

Function.prototype.create= function(){ return new this; };

var foo = Foo.create();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what i'm looking for. Your solution involves creating a create method for each subclass, which i want to be done automatically.

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying. i'll do ya one better in an edit to the answer.

Comment: This would be the way to go, though I think OP also wants to set up inheritance at the same time *(beyond just the automatic interitance from `Object.prototype`)*.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: this is the minimal code to do what he wants, it's meant to be a starting point as it can't be any simpler as-is. there is plenty of room for an Object.create call or whatever is needed. this is simply a template that uses no hard-coded names to do it's magic, letting it be applied anywhere.

Comment: Thanks but are you sure this works ? It seems to me that it will add a non-static method "create" to each instance of the class Foo while not adding a static one.

Comment: no, it will not add any member to the instances derived. it add an inherited static method to the constructor itself, not to the return. i know it seems to be too dang simple to be of use, but that's exactly why i love JS so much...

Comment: Ho i didn't see you wrote 'Function', i read it 'Foo' :D
I'll try this, thanks. EDIT: That would cause problem if another library does the same thing. Isn't it a bad practice ?

Comment: @Virus721: it might.  i doubt it, and _create() or something would provide more insurance. for example, Object blocks it because it has it's own .create. But, you said you didn't want to specify each time it was used. I don't see a way to do it to anything between 1 and every times. you can just make it a function that you call on a constructor to upgrade that constructor, something like: function upgrade(base){ base.prototype.create= function(){ return new this; };}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but it might help.

```
var Foo = {
    create: function () {
        function F() {}

        // Add any default properties/methods/etc.
        F.prototype.bar = true;
        F.prototype.dr = function() { return "Pepper"; };

        // Return a new object containing defaults listed above
        return new F();
    }
};

var baz = Foo.create();
```